# Where to download files referenced in "Object Disappearance for Object Discovery"?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I wanted to download the dataset used in the paper ["Object Disappearance for Object Discovery"](http://wiki.ros.org/Papers/IROS2012_Mason_Marthi_Parr) .
However, the link http://pr.willowgarage.com/data/mobileobjects/small.bag from the ROS wiki page seems to be outdated now, is there still any way of downloading this rosbag dataset?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339184/where-to-download-files-referenced-in-%22object-disappearance-for-object-discovery%22?/) by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2019-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIRC, all files that were hosted at `pr.willowgarage.com` have been moved to `download.ros.org`.

You should find the particular file you're after here: [download.ros.org/data/mobileobjects](http://download.ros.org/data/mobileobjects).

---

Edit: I've also fixed the wiki page ([diff](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/Papers/IROS2012_Mason_Marthi_Parr?action=diff&rev2=15&rev1=14)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1